# Cannot install packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, syntax-error, jetbrains-ide

I've been trying to install some Python packages for data science: NumPy, Pandas, etc., in PyCharm which is the IDE I use. It keeps bringing up "Error occurred when installing package 'name_of_package'. Details..."
Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\plugins\python-      ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 114, in main
        do_install(pkgs)
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 59, in do_install
        run_pip(['install'] + pkgs)
      File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2023.1.4\plugins\python-ce\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
        runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 226, in run_module
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 98, in _run_module_code
      File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main_parser.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip._internal.build_env import get_runnable_pip
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\build_env.py", line 20, in <module>
        from pip._internal.cli.spinners import open_spinner
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\spinners.py", line 9, in <module>
        from pip._internal.utils.logging import get_indentation
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\logging.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 37, in <module>
        from pip._vendor.pep517 import Pep517HookCaller
      File "C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
        from .wrappers import *  # noqa: F401, F403
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    SyntaxError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

What could be the problem?

I tried using the pip install command in the terminal, but the same error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should create an virtual environement to separate python dependecies from your PC dependencies !

Do it with : python3.11 -m venv name_of_your_env

And activate it with : ./env/Scripts/activate.ps1

then just install your packages

Comment: `C:\Users\...\Desktop\PycharmProjects\venv` already looks like a virtual environment directory

Comment: I have already created a virtual environment